# How can I open the device's calculator on click in Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic2

I want to open device's calculator in my Ionic 2 App when the user clicks on "Open Calculator".

I'm able to open the device's dialing screen by using the code below but it's not working for the calculator.

```
<a href="tel: 111111111" style="text-decoration:none;">Call us</a>

<a href="calculator:*" style="text-decoration:none;">Open Calculator</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **no URL scheme** for the calculator (neither Android nor iOS), you have to implement the function inside your app.

Comment: I get that, but is there any other approach to launch default calculator app or for that sake any external app which doesn't have URL scheme? Appreciate your quick response.